# processing two of many concurrent results already, optimization - architecture? algorithm?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, optimization, concurrency

I am downloading data from two times a dozen sources, via `threading.Thread()`. The special property of my case is that data processing can already start when *certain two* such sources are ready (Not any two, but predefined two, pairwise).

First approach is to download all sources, and

```
for all t in threads: t.join()
```

to wait until all downloads have finished, and *then* start the data processing, because then I can be sure to have everything I need, for the data processing.

It will already be fast, but then the data processing only starts after *all* sources have completed downloading. How to get the last bit of optimization now?

I am wondering if perhaps there is a canonic CS way to solve this question of starting tasks when the input collection is only partly done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general CS terms what you are looking for is language features that enable **composition of tasks**.

For example, in C# if you use `Task` instead of `Thread` you can use `Task.WhenAll()` to wait for each pair of subtasks to complete (as a `Task` itself) and then `ContinueWith` whatever you need to do with that pair of results.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    Task a = ...
    Task b = ...
    Task ab = Task.WhenAll(a,b).ContinueWith(...);
    ... 

    var result = Task.WhenAll(ab, ab, bc, ...).Result;
```

You could also look into Reactive Extensions that are becoming available in many programming languages. These enable composition of observable sequences of results in a push model. For example [zip](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md) in RxJS would allow you to trigger a next step whenever both of its input sequences have produced a result.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting to know that this option is provided in .NET language ... it says:

"Creates a task that will complete when all ... objects in an array have completed."

which however is exactly what I am already doing (in Python).

Comment: Ah, you mean ... I could make subtasks of each of the pairs. Yes yes yes. I will think about that. Thanks!

Comment: "wait for each pair of subtasks"

Comment: @akrueger see example I added to clarify how this could work. Oh, and make the Tasks return a result, don't actually use void() Tasks, because (i) it's a best practice and (ii) you can easily aggregate the results.

Comment: Looks like Python 3 would have [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) for Tasks. But the general idea = grouping the two threads together, and when both ready, starting the data processing ... was the main idea that I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @krueger Sorry, just realized you question isn't tagged with a language, My answer was for C# / .NET.

Comment: yes, and ... all languages can do similar things, and I understood what you've shown me ... so your answers are definitely helpful. :-)